# Anchor links in a React app work on desktop and all android browsers, but not iOS devices

Tags: html, ios, reactjs

I load some HTML via a HTTP call and display it on site. The structure is very simple, for example

```
<ol>
  <li><a href="#intro">Introduction</a></li>
  ...
</ol>

...

<h2>1.  <a class="anchor" id="intro"></a>Introduction</h2>
```

Clicking the anchor redirects to a page looking like
      `website.com/terms-and-conditions#intro`

The links work as expected on desktop Firefox and Chrome, on a Galaxy S8 and S9 on Firefox and Chrome, but do not work on an iPhone 7 or an iPad pro on either Chrome or Safari. The page does not move, but the link is still pushed on to the browsers history, i.e., pressing the back button will navigate back and you will still be in the same place.

I have tried swapping the `id` attribute to a `name` attribute and also having both, which does not work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you use the full url? `http://something.com/#intro` ?

Comment: It does not, that causes a full page refresh and the content is loaded asynchronously